# How to Adjust Recyclerview Item Height based on Textview Content length

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

[image: RecyclerView with Post Content]

I have a recyclerView that is being populated.

The problem I am facing now, I want each Textview Height in the RecyclerView holder Item Row to be adjusted to fit the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use wrap_content when defining height of textview for that recyclerview item and also remove fix heights if any either in parent layout or in textview.

Comment: thank you, I was properly doing this wrongly before. In my activity that displays the full post, I have a recyclerview beneath it, This layout stretches and overlaps with the recyclerview, How do I fix this?